# Wicket DropDownChoice setting to null value on page refresh

Tags: wicket

I have a panel inside a panel. Outer panel contains 2 drop downs and a couple of text boxes. Inner panel is repeatable. I can add or delete inner panel by using  buttons on outer panel. It will ask for confirmation(modal window) before deleting the panel. Issue is, if modal window is opened,then closed and refreshed the page, values in the drop down are setting to null. It is not showing previous value. 
Please help me to resolve my problem.

Comment: Show us some code. It is hard to guess what you do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Your DropDownChoice component model / object is probably being set to null.

Without any code it is impossible to tell exactly why this happens but check your models for those components.